# Python csv exporting limited to 8KB?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Can someone tell me what's wrong with this code? It's based off an old project, I'm trying to implement multiple URLs rather than just one.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen
from datetime import datetime
import csv
import sys
import os
import smtplib
import config

# Craigslist search URL
SEARCH_URL = ['http://auburn.craigslist.org/search/sss?query={0}', 'http://bham.craigslist.org/search/sss?query={0}', 'http://dothan.craigslist.org/search/sss?query={0}', 'http://shoals.craigslist.org/search/sss?query={0}', 'http://gadsden.craigslist.org/search/sss?query={0}', 'http://huntsville.craigslist.org/search/sss?query={0}', 'http://auburn.craigslist.org/search/sss?query={0}', 'http://bham.craigslist.org/search/sss?query={0}',  'http://virgin.craigslist.org/search/sss?query={0}']
BASE_URL = "craigslist.org"

class Result:
    """ Creates object from passed in HTML. Should be one row element from base search"""
    def __init__(self, row):
       self.url = row.find("a", "result-title")['href']
       if row.find("span", "result-price"):
          self.price = row.find("span", "result-price").get_text()
       else:
          self.price = "NA"
       self.create_date = row.find('time').get('datetime')
       self.title = row.find('a', 'result-title').get_text()

    def print_out(self):
       print "Title: " + self.title
       print "Price: " + self.price
       print "Creation Date: " + self.create_date
       print "URL: " + self.url
       print


def parse_results(search_term):
    results = []
    search_term = search_term.strip().replace(' ', '+')
    search_url = [url.format(search_term) for url in SEARCH_URL]
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url).read())
    rows = soup.find_all("li", "result-row")
    for row in rows:
       formattedResult = Result(row)
       results.append(formattedResult)
    return results

def record_results(results):
    """ Writes URLs to file so we can keep track of what posts have been seen """
    with open('results.csv', 'w') as f:
       for x in results:
          f.write(x.url)
          f.write("\n")

def has_new_records(results):
    current_posts = [x.url for x in results]
    fields = ["url"]
    if not os.path.exists('results.csv'):
       return True

    with open('results.csv', 'r') as f:
       reader = csv.DictReader(f, fieldnames=fields, delimiter='|')
       seen_posts = [row['url'] for row in reader]

    is_new = False
    for post in current_posts:
       if post in seen_posts:
          pass
       else:
          is_new = True
    return is_new

def send_text(phone_number, msg):
    fromaddr = "Craigslist Checker"
    toaddrs = phone_number + "@att.net"
    msg = ("From:{0}\r\nTo:{1}\r\nSubject:New Craigslist Result\r\n\r\n{2}").format(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg)
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
    server.starttls()
    server.login(config.data['username'], config.data['password'])
    server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg)
    server.quit()

def get_current_time():
    return datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    PHONE_NUMBER = config.data['phone']
    SEARCH_TERM = sys.argv[1]

    if len(PHONE_NUMBER) != 10:
       print "Phone numbers must be 10 digits! Please change in config.\n"
       sys.exit(1)

    results = parse_results(SEARCH_TERM)

    # Send an SMS message if there are new results. Only send first result to avoid spamming texts.
    if has_new_records(results):
       message = "Title: {0}\nPrice: {1}\nURL: {2}".format(results[0].title, results[0].price, results[0].url)
       print "[{0}] There are new results - sending text message to {1}".format(get_current_time(), PHONE_NUMBER)
       send_text(PHONE_NUMBER, message)
       record_results(results)
    else:
       print "[{0}] No new results - will try again later".format(get_current_time())
```

if anyone could fix this code and explain a bit more in details regarding why this was failing, i would forever be in your debt

Update: It now doesn't give out more than (Exactly) 8KB in `results.csv`.

Answer (score 3):

Your `SEARCH_URL` is not a string, it's a list of strings. So, you have to convert them individually. Something like

```
search_urls = [url.format(search_term) for url in SEARCH_URLS]
```

Comment: it returns this error instead `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'timeout'`

Comment: @AndrewWilliams: which line gives that? also, do you pass each `search_url` individually??

Comment: it's no specific code, i don't call nor use the attribute `timeout`. do i have to pass all urls individually? (200+)



`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "craigslist.py", line 92, in <module>
    results = parse_results(SEARCH_TERM)
  File "craigslist.py", line 39, in parse_results
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(search_url).read())
  File "c:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 395, in open
    req.timeout = timeout
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'timeout'`

Comment: @AndrewWilliams: you are probably passing the whole list of strings, instead of a single string, to `urlopen`

Comment: My bad, it was my mistake. Fixed it, however, now it only scrapes 2-3 urls, rather than all the urls specified. No errors given.

Comment: @AndrewWilliams: in your example the list does have 2-3 urls. Don't know which urls are specified.

Comment: It genuinely seems to be a bug; I removed the huge url list as to not cram the src section, it seems to limit the CSV export to 8KB. When i delete the `results.csv` and run it again, it has no issue, but after it reaches exactly 8KB in size, it breaks the script. Any ideas?

Comment: @AndrewWilliams: can't reproduce your scenario obviously, so, no ideas. however, it's very unlikely that something as basic as `write` is bugged